# \textdagger and related symbols give error in point meta=symbolic in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When using `\textdagger` in `point meta={symbolic=\textdagger}` this gives me an error when compiling

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding 
                              /\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape 
l.18     {(0,0) (1,2) (2,3)};
```

Comparable symbols (e.g. `\textdaggerdbl` or `\textbullet`) give the same error. I can replace `\textdagger` by `$\dagger$` and then there is no error anymore. However, I am using `point meta=explicit symbolic`, where the symbols are defined in a table file, and one of the symbols is `\textdagger`. At one point this worked correctly, so I am not sure what changed.

Minimal (not) working example is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
      nodes near coords,
      point meta={symbolic=\textdagger}]
    \addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates
    {(0,0) (1,2) (2,3)};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am using `TeX Live 2015`, and I just updated all packages using `tlmgr update --all`.

Comment: Try `\edef\edeftextdagger{\textdagger}` and you will see similar error.

Comment: Why not `\renewcommand{\textdagger}{$\dagger$}`.

Comment: Yes, I could do that indeed. Still, this probably points to a bug somewhere, I guess. Moreover, you would have to do this for every symbol being used.

Comment: Hmm, indeed. Any idea of a solution @Symbol1?

Comment: Regardless, that is not a wise choice of a marker. Please avoid such archaic symbols that is remnant of older articles.

Comment: @percusse it is actually for indicating the significance of certain results (the actual plot is more complicated than this example), for normal plotting I wouldn't use it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some LaTeX symbols contain font-commands because they are bond to corresponding fonts. Such font-commands are rather dangerous in that you cannot put them into an `\edef`.

However, most magics of PGFPLOTS are achieved by enormous `\edef`'s. Therefore it becomes a "feature", instead of a bug, that one must try their best to avoid those symbols, as well as font commands.

To be specific, we see the definition of the keys at `pgfplots.code.tex` line 3507

> ```
> /pgfplots/point meta/symbolic/.style={/pgfplots/point meta/TeX code symbolic={\edef\pgfplotspointmeta{#1}}},
> ```

And that `\edef` ruins everything.

To get over it, we use `TeX code symbolic` to replace `symbolic`. That is,

```
point meta={TeX code symbolic=\def\pgfplotspointmeta{\textdagger}}
```

or

```
point meta/TeX code symbolic=\def\pgfplotspointmeta{\textdagger}
```

A complete example goes like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        nodes near coords,
        point meta/TeX code symbolic=\def\pgfplotspointmeta{\textdagger}]
      \addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates
      {(0,0) (1,2) (2,3)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Workaround No.2

This is a hacky one. One might guess that our `\textdagger` meets `\edef` only once, so we might add a one-time protection

```
point meta={symbolic=\noexpand\textdagger}
```

or

```
point meta/symbolic=\noexpand\textdagger
```

Comment: Thanks! I traced it back to this particular [commit](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/code/ci/8229afd3e84d60495782b6bbe86c351b3396a858), which changed the `\def` to an `\edef`.